# Duplicate screen name warning when nesting tab navigation within stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am following these [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/) to nest a tab navigator within a stack navigator:

but when I run the code locally I get a duplicate name warning:

```
iOS Bundling complete 1657ms
 WARN  Found screens with the same name nested inside one another. Check:

Home, Home > Home
```

is this expected behavior? I am running these versions of the navigaiton libraries:

```
 npm list @react-navigation/native-stack  @react-navigation/bottom-tabs                                           doms@MacBook-Pro
metis@1.0.0 /Users/doms/ReactNativeMetis/Metis
├── @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.5.7
└── @react-navigation/native-stack@6.9.12
```

Here is the code that gives the warning when I run locally but works fine in [expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@melampus123/react-navigation):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function EmptyScreen() {
  return <View />;
}

function Home({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Profile"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
      />
      <Button
        title="Go to Settings"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={EmptyScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={EmptyScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabs} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={EmptyScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={EmptyScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you post the code for both navigators?

Comment: yes certainly - added code and a link to expo snack

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have a screen named "Home" in each navigator. To fix, simply rename one of your screens so that it is unique. Something like this for example:

```
function HomeTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={EmptyScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={EmptyScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Hometabs" component={HomeTabs} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={EmptyScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={EmptyScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```